# SELECT To_Number('0001000') FROM DUAL;

Tags: oracle

```
CASE 
   WHEN IS_NUMBER(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE (SSN, ''\D'', ''''),-4)) IS NOT NULL 
     THEN To_Number(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE (SSN, ''\D'', ''''),-4)) 
   ELSE 0000 
END AS SSN4,
```

SSN in source table (varchar2) are as : `123-23-1234`, `XX-XX-XXXX`, `123-23-0001`
Expected output (number): `1234`, `0000`, `0001` respectively

Comment: Don't wrap your number in `To_Number()`? Numbers don't have leading 0's. I have a suspicion you aren't sharing what you are a REALLY trying to do though. Whatever it is, this isn't the solution.

Comment: I think you mean "Leading" zeros, no?  THis quesion needs more details, please

Comment: Basically I need the last four digits for the Social Security number which is a varchar in a source table but is a number in a target table. Also, the social security number has a hyphen, (-) in between and some don't. Also, few are in characters in the source table. If ssn has any other values than four digits, at last, it should default to 0000. So the baseline is I need four numbers in my target table.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Sorry my bad, i meant leading 0's

Comment: So take a substring of the varchar pLease edit the question and show the two fields definitions, example values, and exptect output. please.

Comment: @JNevill I have tried with CASE WHEN IS_NUMBER(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE (MBR.MEM_SSN, ''\D'', ''''),-4)) IS NOT NULL THEN To_Number(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE (MBR.MEM_SSN, ''\D'', ''''),-4)) ELSE 0000 END AS SSN4,  This works but to_number is removing leading 0's

Comment: Why not just do: `CASE WHEN IS_NUMBER(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE (MBR.MEM_SSN, ''\D'', ''''),-4)) IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE (MBR.MEM_SSN, ''\D'', ''''),-4) ELSE '0000' END AS SSN4` So you can test if it's a number (but not actually convert it, since you don't want to actually store-it/treat-it as a number. It's merely a numeric string and should be kept as such.

Comment: What does your function `is_number()` do? It's not an Oracle built-in function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it checks if a parameter provided is number or not, with oracle function TO_NUMBER

Comment: If you're on 12c R2 or later use [the Oracle built-in `validate_conversion()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) instead of IS_NUMBER().

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your initial value. E.g. just store it at the [temporary session table](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html) first and do join with it at final (don't forget clear it before and add hint `on commit preserve rows`, which is needed if you want to read data from cursor).

`Number` Oracle type doesn't have information about leading zeros. E.g. `0012` is the same with `12` in memory. Therefore it is better to preserve mapping.